# Java's URLConnection not receiving entire binary file

Tags: java, http, binary, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am currently working on a school that encompasses creating a P2P client for a standard we came up with in class that uses HTTP to request chunks of a binary file from peers. We are allowed to us Java's HTTP libraries to make these requests, however I am hitting a major problem with these libraries. All chunks of a file will be served up in chunks that are <=64KB, but when I use the following code, the max amount of bytes that I receive is around 15040 even though the content-length of the response is  64KB:

```
String response = "";

URL url = new URL(uriPath);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection ();

conn.setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000);
conn.setReadTimeout(30 * 1000);

InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int c;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

while ((c = stream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    byteArrayOut.write(buffer,0,c);
}

body = byteArrayOut.toByteArray();


stream.close();
result.put(Constants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, conn.getHeaderField(Constants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH));
result.put(Constants.HEADER_CONTENT_CHECKSUM, conn.getHeaderField(Constants.HEADER_CONTENT_CHECKSUM));
result.put(Constants.KEY_BODY, new String(body));
```

We've tested our server component, and that serves the file correctly when accessing a chunk with wget or in a browser - this java client is the only problematic client we were able to find.

Is this a problem with Java's URLConnection class, or is there something in my code that is wrong with reading a binary file that is returned in a response?

Note: I am using Java 1.6 in Eclipse and from the command line.

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with that code. Does your server component provide the Content-Length header with correct data?

Comment: Try replacing everything after `conn.getInputStream()` with [`ByteStreams.toByteArray()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)) (from the [Guava Library](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)).

Comment: Isn't "toString" on a ByteArrayOutputStream dubious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that the max amount of bytes is 15040? Did you byteArrayOut.toByteArray().length or did you do new String(byteArrayOut.toByteArray()).length()?

Creating a new String from a byte array that has binary content is likely to give unpredictable results. Use a FileOutputStream and open the file.